# How do i delete an specific object inside a nested field based on a condition in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to delete a object inside an array of object that is the nested field in elasticsearch based on a condition please help me do this or let me know if i can update the value of fields inside an existing document. Here i am using painless script and ES v7.3

my doc:

```
"_source" : {
"connecto_score" : [
  {
    "model" : "puv",
    "value" : "70"
  }
]
}
```

Now I want to make such a script that if a next object comes to index then check its model if it exist then update its "value" or either delete that object completely and index a the new object with the same model.  And if the model does not exist then make a new object.

```
 POST segmentation_v2/_update/Z_nM_2wBjkGOA-r6ArOb
{
"scripted_upsert": true,
"script": {
"lang": "painless",
"source": "boolean contains(def x, def y){for (item in x) { if (item['model'] == y){return true}}return false } if(!ctx._source.containsKey('connecto_score')){ctx._source['connecto_score']=[]} if(!contains(ctx._source.connecto_score, params.object.model)) {ctx._source.connecto_score.add(params.object)}",
"params": {
  "object": {
    "model": "puv",
    "value": "70"
  }
}
},
"upsert" : {}
}
```

Adding a new object is working fine.

But when i try to remove or update it using ctx._source.connecto_score.removeif(model == params.object.model) it gives this exception.

Exception:

```
"lang": "painless",
  "caused_by": {
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Variable [model] is not defined."
  }
```

Comment: you can access model using object.model as defined in params

Comment: u did not understood the problem, i have sorted the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear, you can share the answer it may be useful to someone in the future